# Angular 6 generate excel file with sheetJs but removing some keys?

Tags: excel, angular, angular6, sheetjs

I have this JSON:

```
[{"name":"peter",
"surname":"cage",
"nickname": "peterbob", 
"city":{"id":130, "name":"GreatCity"}
},

{"name":"james",
"surname":"parot",
"nickname": "mrj", 
"city":{"id":142, "name":"OtherCity"}
},
...]
```

I want to generate an Excel file using SheetJs js-xlsx for Angular 6, this is my attempt:

```
const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(myjson);
const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
```

This generates an Excel file with all the JSON object keys and works fine. But I want to generate an Excel file with **only "name" and "city" name**. Is that possible?

Comment: For that, you need to create one separate JSON array which contains only "name" and "city".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map your data before creating excel file:

```
const data = JSON.parse(myjson).map(i => ({ name: i.name, city: i.city }));
const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(JSON.stringify(data));
```